# Retrieving values from a URL page

Tags: android, html

How do you retrieve the value (`<value>`) from a URL using the id (`<id>`) if the HTML page has this kind of format (refer to first code sample)

Format of the HTML page:

```
<form>
 <text>
  <id>time</id>
  <value>10am</value>
 </text>
 <text>
  <id>date</id>
  <value>June 19, 2018</value>
 </text>
 <text>
  <id>location</id>
  <value>New York</value>
 </text>
<form>
```

If i have a HTML format with an id and a value attribute on one tag:

```
<input id="time" value="11am">
```

I can simply get the value by using this code (Written on Java):

```
private void getInformation() {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     try {
       Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://192.1.1.0/").get();
       Element time = doc.getElementById("time");
       Log.d("myLog", "time: " + time.attr("value"))
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {

         }
       });
     } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("myLog", "e: " + e)
     }
   }).start();
  }
}
```

But i don't have any idea how to retrieve values from an html with a format same as the first one i posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        Element element=doc.getDocumentElement();
        element.normalize();

         NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("text");

         for (int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
               Element element2 = (Element) node;
               Log.d("TAG",getValue("id")));
               Log.d("TAG",getValue("value")));


            }
         }

      } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

   }

   private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
      NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
      Node node = nodeList.item(0);
      return node.getNodeValue();
   }
```

let me know if this works